js node test use before outside of describe
as you can see from the before image, out of the describe it is not called, but all the others are.
There's a reason or it doesn't work, that's it.
If I put it in describe it works.

import {
  before,
  beforeEach,
  after,
  afterEach,
  describe,
  it,
  test,
} from "node:test";
import assert from "node:assert";

import { add, subtract } from "../index.js";

before(function () {
  console.log("before");
});
beforeEach(function () {
  console.log("beforeEach");
});
afterEach(function () {
  console.log("afterEach");
});
after(function () {
  console.log("after");
});

describe("Arithmetic Operations", () => {
  it("should correctly add two numbers", () => {
    const result = add(2, 3);
    assert.strictEqual(result, 5);
  });

  it("should correctly subtract two numbers", () => {
    const result = subtract(5, 3);
    assert.strictEqual(result, 2);
  });
});


What node version are you using?

So what exactly is the question?

@TBA: node v18.17.1

@Mureinik: The one described, why is the word "before" not printed.

This seems like a bug in the Node.js test runner, which isn't completely surprising given that you're using Node.js 18.17.1 and the test runner was only declared stable in Node.js 20.0.0.
With Node.js 18.17.1, I was able to consistently reproduce this behavior:
➜  nvm use 18.17.1
Now using node v18.17.1 (npm v9.6.7)
➜  node node.test.js 
beforeEach
afterEach
beforeEach
afterEach
▶ Arithmetic Operations
  ✔ should correctly add two numbers (0.834959ms)
  ✔ should correctly subtract two numbers (0.168333ms)
▶ Arithmetic Operations (1.795125ms)

after
ℹ tests 2
ℹ suites 1
ℹ pass 2
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 0.213542

However, once I switched to the latest Node.js version (22.3.0 at the time of writing), this code indeed works as expected:
➜  nvm use 22.3.0
Now using node v22.3.0 (npm v10.8.1)
➜  node node.test.js
before
beforeEach
afterEach
beforeEach
afterEach
after
▶ Arithmetic Operations
  ✔ should correctly add two numbers (0.517375ms)
  ✔ should correctly subtract two numbers (0.674292ms)
▶ Arithmetic Operations (1.538292ms)
ℹ tests 2
ℹ suites 1
ℹ pass 2
ℹ fail 0
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 6.906708


Perfect excellent, thx. A doubt arises in my mind, whether perhaps after made more sense for it to be printed after all the describe which does not happen with the v22.3.0 version.
Can you tell me:
why is duration_ms so high in v22.3.0 compared to v18.17.1 even if we are talking about ms?

@Paul I'm guessing that the older version doesn't count the before[Each]/after[Each] callbacks and the newer one does. Note that the tests themselves just do some basic math while the callbacks perform I/O to stdout which should be an order of magnitude slower.

But when he says that:
Arithmetic Operations (1.538292ms) would be the total time to run everything, but why do you think if I do:
should correctly add two numbers (0.517375ms)+should correctly subtract two numbers (0.674292ms) doesn't it always give me the same result for the underlying operations that we don't know?
